# Semi_join filtering an R dataframe conditionally

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering

Data frame 1 (df1) has the following columns:

```
Year ID1 ID2 V1 V2 ....
```

Data frame 2 (df2) has the following columns:

```
Year ID
```

I would like to do a semi_join using df2 to filter df1 by both Year and ID, except I would like to keep observations in df1 where ID matches in either ID1 or ID2. I'm not sure if dplyr's semi_join has a way of doing this or if another method is required.

Edit:

```
df1 = data.frame(Year = c(rep(2000,5), rep(2001,5)), 
                 ID1 = 1:5, 
                 ID2 = 5:1,
                 V1 = seq(1,10, length.out = 10))
df2 = data.frame(Year = c(2000,2000,2001,2001), ID = c(1,2,1,3))
```

Output

```
 Year ID1 ID2 V1
 2000 1   5    1
 2000 2   4    2
 2000 4   2    4
 2000 5   1    5
 2001 1   5    6
 2001 3   3    8
 2001 5   1   10
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible sample data (e.g. using `dput`) and matching expected output.

Comment: Perhaps it is an optioen to first cast df1 to the appropriate long format, and then join?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Added that to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not elegant, but you could do a semi-join on each ID separately and then union the results:

```
bind_rows(
  semi_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID1" = "ID"),
  semi_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID2" = "ID")
) %>%
  distinct()
```

(Untested, without a sample of the dataset.)

Comment: If I could guarantee that ID1 and ID2 for the same observation would never equal, would I still need to apply distinct() at the end?

Comment: You would still need `distinct()`, just in case both `ID1` and `ID2` are in `df2$ID`.  But if you could guarantee that `ID1` and `ID2` for the same observation are never _both_ in `df2$ID`, then you could omit `distinct()`.  (To me, checking that condition seems harder than using `distinct()`.  But if your data is conveniently structured and you know that condition will be met, go for it!)